# Iterate list look for boolean attribute, return default false

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of objects, each object has a boolean attribute. For example,

```
public class A {
   private boolean isAvailable;
}
```

I would like to iterate this list, get the value of "isavailable" of the first element in the list. If the list is empty or null, then I would like to return false.

Can I do this efficiently with Java8 streams?

Comment: Show your attempt?

Answer (score 1):

Of course that is possible with Java Streams:

```
boolean result = list.stream().findFirst().map(A::isAvailable).orElse(false);
```

Use the [`findFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) method to get the first value of the list if present. [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) `isAvailable` and return `false` if the list is empty.

**I would strongly discourage using null as list value.** Use an empty list instead.

But if you want to do so you can use an `Optional` to wrap the list:

```
boolean result = Optional.ofNullable(list)
        .flatMap(l -> l.stream().findFirst().map(A::isAvailable))
        .orElse(false);
```

Comment: Or just `boolean result = list!=null && !list.isEmpty() && list.get(0).isAvailable();`